# Can't send mail with SwiftMailer using SmtpTransport in live environment but can send in localhost

Tags: php, email, sendmail, swiftmailer

I am using SwiftMailer to send a simple mail. But when I use the **SmtpTransport** (with host, username and a password) method, I get the following error of using 2 possible authenticators. I searched the issue on stackoverflow but could not find a solution.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxx@yyyyyyyy.com" using 2 possible authenticators' in /home/yyyyyyyy/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php:181 Stack trace: #0 
/home/yyyyyyyy/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(307): Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler->afterEhlo(Object(Swift_SmtpTransport)) #1 
/home/yyyyyyyy/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(118): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doHeloCommand() #2 
/home/yyyyyyyy/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(79): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 
/home/yyyyyyyy/public_html/testmail.php(51): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 {main} thrown in /home/lexington21/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php on line 181
```

My source is as follows. This source work perfectly in my localhost but not when it is uploaded to the live environment.

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance("SMTPHOST", 25)
->setUsername("user")
->setPassword("pass");

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$to = "abc@aaa.com";
$subject = "Test Mail";
$email_body = "Hi Please confirm if you have received this email.";

$mail = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
->setFrom(array("research@lexingtonstudies.com"))
->setTo(array($to))
->setBcc(array("bcc1@aaa.com", "bcc2@bbb.com"))
->setBody($email_body, 'text/html');

$mailing_result = $mailer->send($mail);
```

I used 465 with ssl but got this error.

```
Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance("SMTPHOST", 465, 'ssl')
```

Error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host SMTPHOST [Connection refused #111]' in /home/yyyyyyyy/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:265 Stack trace: #0 
/home/yyyyyyyy/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(62): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() #1 
/home/yyyyyyyy/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(113): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2 
/home/yyyyyyyy/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(79): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 
/home/yyyyyyyy/public_html/testmail.php(51): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 {main} thrown in /home/yyyyyyyy/public_html/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 265
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: have you tried  changing the port to 465 set the encryption type as SSL.

Comment: have you try different port instead of 25 because some hosting server don't allow 25. please try 465 port .

Comment: @Ohgodwhy changed the question with those. I tried 465 with ssl but i get another error.

Comment: @SheikhJames I used 465 with ssl and got another error. I updated the question with its result.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy tried. similar error. With 25 it works in localhost.

Comment: But how do we know your current host hasn't disabled 25

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Well when I used normal PHP mail() function I could send mails to other emails. But there, I couldn't send mails to the domain's email address. Domain is yyyyyy.com and the email is info@yyyyyy.com. When I used info@yyyyyy.com for TO field, it didn't send any mail to that but to every other email (gmails) were sent.

Comment: @techytee did you find a solution to this problem? Im facing the exact same thing... I can send emails in my local env, but in production keeps failing.

Greets.

Answer (score 1):

The security setting might need to be 'tls' instead of 'ssl' (check with your SMTP host).  Also confirm the port is correct.  And I set Swiftmailer's "local" domain.  Here is the code that works for me in 3 environments: localhost, internal postfix SMTP server, and external SMTP (Mailgun):

```
// $config is an array populated from a config file
$host = $config['host'];
$port = $config['port'] ?: 25;
$user = $config['user'];
$pass = $config['pass'];
$security = 'tls';
if (isset($config['security'])) {
    $security = $config['security'];
}
if (empty($config['security'])) {
    $security = 'tcp';
}

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($host, $port, $security)
    ->setUsername($user)
    ->setPassword($pass);
// Explicitly set HELO domain
$transport->setLocalDomain($host);

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```